# Record in a log when a user changes his password in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, watchdog

I need to record when a user changes his password in drupal 7. When a registered user changes their password the platform should store a record in a database.

I appreciate any guidance.

thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to do something similar the other day and came up with this solution using [`hook_user_presave()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_presave/7)

```
function MYMODULE_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  if (!empty($edit['pass']) && $account->pass != $edit['pass']) {
    watchdog('MYMODULE', t('Password changed for %name', array('%name' => $account->name)));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a [hook_form_user_profile_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) and add an extra [#submit](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#submit_property) handler (to the form) in which you do something like this:

```
if (!empty($form_state['values']['pass']) && $form_state['values']['pass'] != $form_state['values']['current_pass']) {
  watchdog('user', 'The %name changed his password.', array('%name' => $account->name), WATCHDOG_NOTICE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a sandbox module to do this:
https://drupal.org/sandbox/dhalbert/1695174 ("Password Change Log").

It uses a `hook_user_update()` but is otherwise quite similar to the accepted answer.